# Circumventing a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, json

So I know why I have a null reference exception in this case. My question is how I avoid it given this specific use.

I have a function interpreting JSON data like so:

```
public IActionResult SendLine([FromBody] User data) {
    if (_assets.GetPropertyByName(data.Properties.PropertyName) == null) {
        _assets.AddProperty(new Property {
            IsToggle = data.Properties.IsToggle,
            Order = data.Propertis.Order,
            Type = data.Properties.Type,
            PropertyName = data.Properties.PropertyName
        });
    }
    _assets.AddRow(data);
    return Json(data);
}
```

The problem is that the Property class can have null values like so:

```
{
  properties: {
    isToggle: false,
    order: 0,
    type: null,
    propertyName: "Test"
  },
  ....
}
```

So I get why it throws the exception that "properties" is null since it has a null value. However this is as intended. How do I check to see if the propertyName is null without it throwing that error?

EDIT:
I'm not sure how null conditionals would help this case. If I put it here

```
if (_assets.GetPropertyByName(data.Properties?.PropertyName) == null)
```

it will evaluate to null improperly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: *Check* the property value before using it. You can use `if` before you call `AddProperty` , use `?:` to return values based on a condition, `?.` for null-safe dereferencing. You don't have to nest everything, you can use `&&` or `||`  to combine conditions, eg `if (data.Properties!=null && _assets.GetPropertyByName(...)`

Comment: Please be explicit about what you want to happen, what you observe to happen and why that is currently happening. I am not entirely sure what can be null here since you're talking about PropertyName but showing an example where Type is null. Can you please give a solid [mcve] that exhibits the problem so that we're sure we're talking about the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** *Updated my answer after realizing this is probably closer to what you need (?):*

---

If the `if`-clause is where your exception is thrown, just split it up a little more:

```
var propName = data?.Properties?.PropertyName;
var isPropNameFound = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName);
var prop = isPropNameFound ? _assets.GetPropertyByName(propName) : null;

if (isPropNameFound && (prop == null))
{
    // Add new property if name was given, and it 
    // was not found to already have been added?
}
```

That should ensure `propName` is null if either `data.Properties` or `data.Properties.PropertyName` is null, and do so without throwing a NullReferenceException.

After that, it will run the logic in the `if` block only if `propName` had a value, and if `_assets.GetPropertyByName(propName)` did not return anything.